# Is there page control in HTML/CSS which looks and works like UIPageControl in iOS?

Tags: html, css, ios

I am planning to have a page control in my html Application.
Is there a page control in HTML/CSS which looks and works like UIPageControl in iOS?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, it is called the `nav` element.

```
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">.</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">.</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">.</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I'll leave the details up to you.

Comment: Can u point me to a Sample for this. When I tried this it did not give a page control.. Should I include any specific framework?

Comment: @Krishnan As with everything else on your webpage, you need to style it yourself.

Comment: oh ..Thanks for the information..I will test it and once I get the expected result..I will accept the answer.